# change colors of table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to study for my exam and I thought I was doing this right...
I want to change the color of the table (font or background) depending on which cell you click
I thought I was referring to the table right, but this code isn't working... I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate any help or explanation you can offer

```
<html>
     <script language="text/JavaScript">
            function changeFont(color){
                document.getElementbyId("miTabla").style.backgroundColor = color;
            }
            function changeBack(color){
                 document.getLementbyId("miTabla").style.font.color = color;
            }
        </script>
    <body>
         <header>Tabla de ejemplo</header>
         <table id="miTabla" border="2">
                <tr>
                <td>changeFont</td>
                <td onclick="changeFont('#FF0000');">red</td>
                <td onclick="changeFont('#FFFF00');">yellow</td>
                <td onclick="changeFont('#0000FF');">blue</td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td>changeBack</td>
                <td onclick="changeBack('#FFFFFF');">white</td>
                <td onclick="changeBack('#808080');">gray</td>
                <td onclick="changeBack('#000000');">black</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `getLementbyId` and `getElementbyId` to `getElementById` and change `font.color` to `color`.

```
        function changeFont(color){
            document.getElementById("miTabla").style.color = color;
        }
        function changeBack(color){
             document.getElementById("miTabla").style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
```

`changeFont` might also be more appropriately named `changeForeground`.

Comment: hi,tnx for checking out those mistakes... I did your correction but still it isn't working, it's not changing color according to the clicked cell... why? :(

Comment: nevermind!! i found my mystake I was using language="text/JavaScript" instead of type="text/JavaScript" :D

Comment: @IgnacioPochart: you don't need *any* of that. `<script>...</script>` works just fine and is entirely valid.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `backgroundColor` is correct, but what's going on with `font.color`? Where did that come from?

Just use `style.color`.

Also, fix the typo "get�***El***�ementById" in the second one.