# changing color of table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change colors of table with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423846/change-colors-of-table-with-javascript)

for this problem im trying to change the whole table font color or background color depending on which cell is clicked (yellow cell turns all font in the table yellow...)
im pretty sure my syntaxis is correct but my logic sadly, isnt... can you guys point me in the right direction??
this is the code:

```
<html>
<script language="text/JavaScript">
        function changeFont(color){
            document.getElementById("miTabla").style.color = color;
        }
        function changeBack(color){
            document.getElementById("miTabla").style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    </script>
<body>
    <header>Tabla de ejemplo</header>
    <table id="miTabla" border="2">
           <tr onclick="changeFont('red');">
            <td>changeFont</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#FF0000');">red</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#FFFF00');">yellow</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#0000FF');">blue</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>changeBack</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#FFFFFF');">white</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#808080');">gray</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#000000');">black</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: NEVER MIND!!! I  solved it!! :D sorry for the ducplicate close this thread as you see fit

Comment: @IgnacioPochart: you can delete it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
        function changeFont(color){
            document.getElementById("miTabla").style.color = color;
        }
        function changeBack(color){
            document.getElementById("miTabla").style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>Tabla de ejemplo</header>
    <table id="miTabla" border="2">
           <tr>
            <td>changeFont</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#FF0000');">red</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#FFFF00');">yellow</td>
            <td onclick="changeFont('#0000FF');">blue</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>changeBack</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#FFFFFF');">white</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#808080');">gray</td>
            <td onclick="changeBack('#000000');">black</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All you did was put his js in the head of the document, which doesn't make sense in that it's supposed to execute on a click, not immediately when the page loads.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've copied the code locally to test, but it works as intended. When the cell is clicked the function is called. As he had it, the functions were not being found. Give it a shot and if it doesn't work I'll be more than happy to remove the comment =)

Comment: I take back what I said, I apologize.  I've also up-voted you.

Comment: No worries and I appreciate the vote. I was fairly certain it worked for me, but I could have also read the description incorrectly. Seemed to me that's what he was asking for though. Thanks again.